# Applescript to input text to find bar in browser

Tags: applescript

I can start a "Find" operation with the following applescript:

```
activate application "Firefox"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Firefox"
        click menu item "Find" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

How can I then input a string to the find search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activate application "Firefox"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Firefox"
        click menu item "Find" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    keystroke myString
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but would you also know of a way to click on items in the find bar, or to check if it already has text in it? My end goal is to assign the script to a keybinding so that I can have both "Find" and "Find Again" together in a single command.

Comment: Not sure whether you can run javascript in Firefox using applescript or not. In safari there is an option to run js.
Alternatively, you can do `keystroke "f" using command down` for fire search again, and keep doing `keystroke return` to find next item.